# How to remove a column string value from another column string value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df:
col1                      col2
blue water bottle        blue
red wine glass           red
green cup                green
```

I want make another column which will ignore the value of `col2` from `col1`
for example the new column `col3` will be:

```
water bottle
wine glass
green cup
```

I have tried this code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'], ''), axis=1)
```

But I am getting following error:

> AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'", 'occurred at index 0')

How to do it ?

Comment: `df["col3"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["col1"].replace(x["col2"], ""), axis=1)` should work. My guess is you have `None` value somewhere. You could check with `df[df.col1.isnull()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the "col1" for some rows in your dataframe are None. You will need to handle those cases for example by assigning an empty string to `col3`

```
df["col3"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: "" if pd.isnull(x["col1"]) else x["col1"].replace(x["col2"], ""),
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
df[['col','col2']].apply(lambda x: x[0].replace(x[1],''), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
0     water bottle
1       wine glass
2              cup
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop rows with `NaN` entries before apply your lambda:
`df[['col1', 'col2']].dropna().apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'], ''), axis=1)`

Answer (score -1):

This is one way (vectorizing would give a better answer of course)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = ['blue water bottle', 'red wine glass', 'green cup']
df['col2'] = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
df['col3'] = ['', '', '']
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row['col3'] = row['col'].replace(row['col2'], '').strip()
```

[image: pandas string replace]